# Inserting into table from select statement and hardcoded values

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to do something like this:

```sql
INSERT
INTO
  my_test
  (
    name,
    sirname,
    Dept
  )
  VALUES
  (('First Name'),(SELECT sirname, Dept FROM my_test_backup WHERE dept = 500));
```

The error I am getting is too many values.

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to insert a hardcoded value make it part of the select.

```
insert into my_test
   (name, sirname, dept)
   (select 'First Name'
          ,sirname
          ,dept
      from my_test_backup
     where dept = 500)
```

Comment: Btw: you don't need the brackets around the SELECT part.

Comment: I also wanted to know that can i union 4 tables in this query..?

Comment: @Anubhav Aeron: If this answer solves your problem (which it appears to), please accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO my_test( name, sirname, Dept ) 
    (SELECT 'First Name', sirname, Dept FROM my_test_backup WHERE dept = 500)
```

Comment: Same query has been posted by Rene 5 mins ago.

Comment: Actually, I've seen that post after my post. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think it is supposed to be

```
INSERT INTO my_test ( name, sirname, Dept ) 
(SELECT FirstName, sirname, Dept FROM my_test_backup WHERE dept = 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
INSERT INTO my_test ( name, sirname, Dept )
(SELECT 'firstname' as name,sirname, Dept FROM my_test_backup WHERE dept = 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO my_test 
(name, sirname, Dept)

SELECT name, sirname, Dept
FROM my_test_backup
WHERE dept=500;
```